# Novel where single-atom blades bounce off from each other

Tags: story-identification, novel, nanotechnology

A long while ago (5-10 years) I read a science fiction novel in which characters dueled with nanotechnology blades that are [Sharpened to a Single Atom](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SharpenedToASingleAtom).

One aspect I found interesting was that the blades in this story would not cut through other blades that used the same technology, but instead would violently bounce off from them. This meant that in a duel, you were far more likely to be injured by your own blade rebounding than than by your opponent's. In the story, they paraphrased this as something like "your opponent's blade is your weapon, your own blade is his weapon."

I've read through the TV Tropes page linked above, and there are obviously a lot of stories with absurdly sharp blades. But none of them mention the "bouncing off" aspect, so I can't be sure they are the one I'm looking for.

The only other things I can remember are that these blades were held together by a force field. And one of the important duels may have taken place in a body of shallow water, perhaps on an ocean world.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Nice question, you've covered a fair number of points.  Was this an e-book or a physical book?  Do you recall the cover art, or the names of any characters or places?  Was the story mostly set in a single locale, or was there a lot of travelling around?

Comment: I haven't read this but I'm almost positive I've heard about it from friends. Could it be The Chronicles of Amber?

Comment: Hi DavidW, unfortunately I remember almost nothing of the story other than what I've written. It may have been even more than ten years ago that I read it.

Comment: Todd, I through the wikipedia summary and that series seems more fantasy-leaning than I remember. And I didn't see any mention of the aspect I remember. But thanks!

Comment: Did you check all the references on the [TVTropes "Like cannot cut like" page?](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LikeCannotCutLike)

Comment: @JRE good suggestion! Didn't see anything that matched, at least in the Literature section. "A Lord from Planet Earth" comes close but it seems it's only in Russian!

Comment: It sounds like you are describing Larry Niven's variable-sword (cf. "Ringworld"), although I don't recall a story involving their use in a duel.

Comment: There is a type of duel in the book "Wolfling" by Gordon R. Dickson that sounds similar.  More details of the story - https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187809/spy-from-earth-studies-galactic-empire-nobility-and-prevents-plot-to-depose-empe/187810#187810